# Using a GUI hosted from EC2 via SSH

Tags: amazon-web-services, user-interface, ssh, x11, x11-forwarding

Is it possible to launch a GUI (JMeter in my case) from an EC2 cloud instance and view/access this GUI from my localhost? If so how would I do that?

I SSH into EC2, start gui but I receive the following error:

`An error occurred: No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it with non GUI. With GUI if your local S.O is windows you need to install Xming and configure X11 forwarding in Putty or if it's linux search how to export X with ssh.

Comment: Sorry for the rookie question but what does S.O stand for?

Comment: sorry is O.S operating system

Answer (score 0):

Here's what solved my problem. As @drsromero pointed out, you must use X11 forwarding. I am working on a mac to access the JMeter GUI from the remote host where I am running the test, but this should work for accessing any remote GUI from your local machine.

1. Download and install XQuartz
2. Open Xquartz from applications->utilities->XQuartz
3. ssh to remote host using -X or -Y option: `ssh -X host_name@here.com`
4. Open the GUI from the command line of your remote instance as you would on your local machine. The GUI will show on your local machine with DISPLAY variables automatically set but be running remotely.

`